# How to setup a div which will take an "infinite width" (horizontal scroller)?

Tags: css

I would like to draw a simple horizontal scroller.

My problem is my elements inside my scroller don't take an infinite width, so after using 100% of the width parent, the next elem will be display to a new line. 
I was thinking an `absolute div` was taking an infinite width by default but apparently not, how to make it works ?

I specify that the number of elems is dynamic.

[Here is a JSFiddle representing my issue](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/gakqm/4/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it!

```
#scroller {
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
overflow:scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
white-space:nowrap;   
}
```

Comment: Nice, by adding a `vertical-align: top;` on the elements it works great, thanks!

Comment: Vote mine for best answer if it's the solution you chose. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

This is an easy way to do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/gakqm/10/

```css
#scroller-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

#scroller {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.elem {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS:

```
#scroller-wrapper {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:red;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

#scroller {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.elem {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gakqm/15/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add overflow:

```
#scroller {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Yes i have try to add `overflow-x: scroll;` but the elems after the 100% of width go to a new line, same issue.

Comment: Why are you adding the y axe ? It doesn't draw the elems on a same line. I am tryng to draw an horizontal slider.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to overflow, you need the to disable wrapping using the white-space property.

http://jsfiddle.net/gakqm/6/

```
#scroller-wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `white-space:nowrap;` to prevent the elements from wrapping.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/gakqm/12/